# SQL Table Performance - Large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I have a very large table ~55,000,000 records.
Indexes have been added to the most commonly used columns, but the table is still very slow.

Are there any suggestions as to how the tables performance could be improved?
I have thought about partitioning the table, but was not sure it was necessary.

```
--Table
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DriverEmployeeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EobrDeviceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EobrTimestampUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EobrOverallStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Speedometer] [decimal](14, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Odometer] [decimal](14, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Tachometer] [decimal](14, 4) NOT NULL,
    [GpsTimestampUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [GpsLatitude] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [GPSLongitude] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
    [RecordType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FuelEconomyAverage] [decimal](8, 4) NOT NULL,
    [FuelEconomyInstant] [decimal](8, 4) NOT NULL,
    [FuelUseTotal] [decimal](14, 4) NOT NULL,
    [BrakePressure] [decimal](8, 4) NOT NULL,
    [CruiseControlSet] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TransmissionAttained] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [TransmissionSelected] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [IsProcessed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastChangedByUserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EngineRecord] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [NK_EngineRecord] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC,
    [EobrDeviceId] ASC,
    [EobrTimestampUtc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_CompanyLevel] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CompanyLevel] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_CompanyLevel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([DriverEmployeeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_Employee]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_EobrDevice] FOREIGN KEY([EobrDeviceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EobrDevice] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EngineRecord_EobrDevice]
GO



---------------------
--Indexes/Constraints
---------------------


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_EngineRecord] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NC_EngineRecord_Employee] ON [dbo].[EngineRecord] 
(
    [DriverEmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NC_RecordType] ON [dbo].[EngineRecord] 
(
    [RecordType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EngineRecord] ADD  CONSTRAINT [NK_EngineRecord] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC,
    [EobrDeviceId] ASC,
    [EobrTimestampUtc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EngineRecord_DBA] ON [dbo].[EngineRecord] 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC,
    [GpsLatitude] ASC,
    [GPSLongitude] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [EobrDeviceId],
[EobrTimestampUtc]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NC_IsProcessed] ON [dbo].[EngineRecord] 
(
    [IsProcessed] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

EDIT:

Here is a sproc that takes some time to run that is used often.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EngineRecord__GetEobrListToProcessByRecordType]
    @RecordTypeEnum int
AS
DECLARE @ChangeHistory bit -- dummy variable for VS 2008 database project

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT EobrDevice.[Id] as EobrDeviceId, 
    EobrDevice.[UnitId], 
    CompanyGroupRoot.[Id] as CGRootId, 
    CompanyGroup.[Id] as CompanyGroupId, 
    EobrDevice.[CompanyId]
FROM dbo.EobrDevice
    INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyLevel ON EobrDevice.[CompanyId] = CompanyLevel.[Id]
    INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyGroup ON CompanyLevel.ParentGroupId = CompanyGroup.[Id]
    INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyGroupRoot ON CompanyGroup.CGRootId = CompanyGroupRoot.[Id]
WHERE EobrDevice.[Id] IN ( SELECT DISTINCT EngineRecord.EobrDeviceId FROM dbo.EngineRecord WHERE IsProcessed = 0 AND RecordType = @RecordTypeEnum ) 
    AND EobrDevice.UnitId IS NOT NULL
```

EDIT 2:

This is something we run every night to purge out old records. This always takes a lot of time.

```
DECLARE @dt6MonthsPrior datetime
    SET @dt6MonthsPrior = DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())

    SELECT * FROM EngineRecord
    WHERE EngineRecord.EobrTimeStampUtc < @dt6MonthsPrior
    ORDER BY EobrTimestampUtc ASC
```

Comment: We can't fix "the table is slow" - could you show some very specific queries that are slow?

Comment: Yes, thanks  SELECT * FROM EngineRecord
WHERE Odometer > 600000
AND Odometer < 700000
AND Tachometer > 800
AND Tachometer < 900
AND FuelUseTotal IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY EobrTimestampUtc DESC

Comment: Am I missing it or is there no `CLUSTERED` index?

Comment: Well why are you using SELECT *? There is no magic way to return ALL OF THE DATA without needing the time to READ and TRANSMIT and RENDER ALL OF THE DATA.

Comment: @GoatCO yes it's there, there is a clustered unique constraint `NK_EngineRecord`.

Comment: We have at times needed to query this table to find some outlying records, and it has taken significant time 1hr+. I know that with the example I gave it seems kind of dumb to be asking the question, but there are some more complicated sprocs that we run that is taking a lot of time. I will post one of those.

Comment: Please see my EDIT above for one of my SPROCS. Thanks

Comment: Tables aren't slow, *Queries* are slow.

Comment: That `DISTINCT` in your `IN(..)` subquery doesn't help you in any way and *could* be making it extremely slow.  I'd recommend taking it out, or even changing the whole subQuery to an `EXISTS(..)`.

Comment: I made another EDIT with another query we use.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Since the subquery is not correlated, how would `EXISTS` be faster than `IN`?

Comment: @GoatCO Oops, good point, I missed that it wasn't correlated.

Comment: My second edit is the one that really seems to be running slow. At the moment I don't have an index on the timestamp, but is that the only thing I can do to improve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

None of the fields in your `WHERE` criteria are contained in an index.  Indexing those fields will help.  The efficacy of your other indices is impossible to determine without a more thorough understanding of how the table is used.

If you really wanted this query to fly you could have a clustered index on Odometer and Tachometer, but that's probably not reasonable given the table's other uses.

Update:

Your 2nd stored proc doesn't seem like it should be terribly slow, it does seem like the only thing that would help that is an index on the date.

55 million records isn't that big these days, I'm no expert on partitioning, but I don't think you'd see much if any improvement by partitioning your table, I usually don't bother unless I expect a table to exceed a few hundred million records, but in a production environment there are other benefits of partitioning.

Are you certain hardware is not responsible for the poor performance you're seeing?  There are a host of settings/features in SQL Server that affect performance as well.

Comment: What about using a view to do adhoc querying against? Would that make more sense?

Comment: An indexed view could be leveraged, but I'm not terribly familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

An index like this might help this specific query:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.EngineRecord(Odometer, Tachometer) WHERE FuelUseTotal IS NOT NULL;
```

This will help most if you stop ordering by the timestamp.

Comment: @IR0N0RR no, if you need to sort, you need to sort. If that specific query (and that is one that was in the comments, before you edited your question) is run often enough, then maybe alternative indexing would be appropriate, or maybe you could consider [ordering in the app (see #2 here)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/7-things-developers-should-know-about-sql-server/) (knowing nothing about your app). How to architect your entire database and index design around all of your queries is a little out of scope for a single question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to get Execution Plans? You have no index on tach or odo or FuelUse, so your sample query will result in a full table scan. From Sql Management Studio, right click in the query window, select "Include Actual Execution Plan" and then run your query. You will see an output that explains to you the steps SQL server will has to perform to actually run your query. This can be very instructive once you take the time to understand an execution plan.

Also, you might want to investigate covering indexes. These can be a dramatic difference if you have some queries that you use frequently. Of course, like any index, there is more overhead when you add/delete

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the fields in the `WHERE` like Goat CO suggests is a good start, I would also advise to move the `WHERE` condition to the first `INNER JOIN`, that way the temporary table created for further handling is already much smaller after the first `INNER JOIN` (I've seen it do performance wonders)

```
SELECT EobrDevice.[Id] as EobrDeviceId, 
    EobrDevice.[UnitId], 
    CompanyGroupRoot.[Id] as CGRootId, 
    CompanyGroup.[Id] as CompanyGroupId, 
    EobrDevice.[CompanyId]
FROM dbo.EobrDevice
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyLevel 
    ON EobrDevice.UnitId IS NOT NULL
    AND EobrDevice.[CompanyId] = CompanyLevel.[Id]
    AND EobrDevice.[Id] IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT EngineRecord.EobrDeviceId 
        FROM dbo.EngineRecord 
        WHERE IsProcessed = 0 
          AND RecordType = @RecordTypeEnum
    )
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyGroup ON CompanyLevel.ParentGroupId = CompanyGroup.[Id]
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyGroupRoot ON CompanyGroup.CGRootId = CompanyGroupRoot.[Id]
```

I've also moved the `EobrDevice.UnitId IS NOT NULL` condition to be checked first so that checking with other tables and running the subquery only happens when that condition is met.

Comment: If this ever has done performance wonders it is more by luck than judgment, SQL-Server is free to choose whatever order it likes to perform predicates in, and moving them around the query is not guaranteed to have a positive impact, or any impact at all for that matter. Even moving things to subqueries does not always work, as the optimiser can execute outer queries first, e.g. `SELECT a / b FROM (SELECT a, b FROM T WHERE b > 0) T WHERE a / b > 1.0` can still throw divided by 0 error, even though the `WHERE` on the inner query should guarantee there are no 0s in the outer query.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not familiar with SQL-Server's optimiser, I guess you could look at the execution plan to see if this would have any effect. I can't help but think that I'd be surprised if an optimiser changes the `JOIN` order or runs `WHERE` before all tables have been joined as those conditions might reference the columns only available after the join.

Comment: @funkwurm The only way to strictly enforce join order in SQL Server is to join with FORCE ORDER, otherwise SQL will try to determine the optimal order on its own.

Answer (score 0):

PARTITIONNING INDEXES should have an impact in your performance. But they have to be done within appropriate separate drives. You give no information of your hardwares (what are you using, NAS ? SAS Drives ? ... )

Also, Normalization is not always the best choice regarding the objectives of your process, especially for Analytics purpose. Some fields (CompanyLevel, CompanyGroup) denormalized within your main table would have a better impact in your selection - 
Well, every master chef have his own Kitchen, so let's skip this discussion....

The built of your indexes do not fit the way you purge your data. You will get a better performance if you decide to change your

```
[EobrTimestampUtc] ASC
```

change to

```
  [EobrTimestampUtc] DESC
```

will impact the seek index for `EngineRecord.EobrTimeStampUtc < @dt6MonthsPrior`